# what am I doing wrong Swift 3 http request and response

Tags: ios, xcode, swift3

I'm having big problems in a project I'm currently working with.

I've been reading about URLSession various places but all of them seem to be outdated and refers to NSURLSession I thought that they would be fairly similar and they probably are but for a newbie like me I'm lost. what I do is not working and I do not like solutions I find because they all do their work in a controller..

http://swiftdeveloperblog.com/image-upload-with-progress-bar-example-in-swift/
this one for instance. I'm using the PHP script but wanted to make a networking layer I could invoke and use at will. but I'm lacking a good resource from where I could learn about how to use this api.

every place I find is similar to the link above or older. the few newer seem to also follow the pattern without really explaining how to use this api.

at the same time I'm new to the delegate pattern in fact I only know that it is something that is heavily used in this Api but I have no IDEA how or why.
Basically I need help finding my way to solve this problem here:

I've tried to do something like this:

```
    public class NetworkPostRequestor:NSObject,NetworkPostRequestingProtocol,URLSessionTaskDelegate,URLSessionDataDelegate
{
    public var _response:HTTPURLResponse
    public override init()
    {
        _response = HTTPURLResponse()
    }
    public func post(data: Data, url: URL)
    {
        var request = URLRequest(url: url)
        request.httpMethod = "POST"
        request.setValue("Keep-Alive", forHTTPHeaderField: "Connection")
        let configuration = URLSessionConfiguration.default
        let session = URLSession(configuration: configuration,delegate: self, delegateQueue: OperationQueue.main)
        let task = session.uploadTask(with: request, from: data)
        task.resume()

    }
    public func urlSession(_ session: URLSession, dataTask: URLSessionDataTask, didReceive response: URLResponse, completionHandler: @escaping (URLSession.ResponseDisposition) -> Void)
    {
       _response = response as! HTTPURLResponse
    }
}
```

however I never even hit the PHPserver. the server when hit will say something like this in the terminal:

```
    [Tue Mar  7 11:43:20 2017] 192.168.250.100:64265 [200]: /
    [Tue Mar  7 11:43:20 2017] 192.168.250.100:64266 [404]: /favicon.ico - No such file or directory
```

Well that is when I hit it with my browser and there is no image with it. but alt least I know that it will write something with the terminal if it hits it. Nothing happens And without a resource to teach me this api I'm afraid I will never learn how to fix this or even if I'm doing something completely wrong.

I'm using Swift 3 and Xcode 8.2.1

**Edit:**

I've added this method to the class and found that I hit it every single time.

```
  public func urlSession(_ session: URLSession, task: URLSessionTask, didCompleteWithError error: Error?)
{
    _error = error.debugDescription
}
```

the debug description have this string "some"

Comment: Would like to know why someone gave me a minus ? is there some way I could change my post for rectifying the reason I got a minus vote?

Comment: I see absolutely nothing wrong with your post. The question is valid, you have added the explanation on what you have tried and described the result you have. The snippets are added, question is nicely formatted...

Comment: @AshleyMills tried to remove the parts that you pointed out. thanks for informing me of my blunder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I never used this exact procedure with tasks but rather use the methods with callback. I am not sure if in the background there should be much of a difference though.

So to generate the session (seems pretty close to your):

```
let configuration = URLSessionConfiguration.default
let session = URLSession(configuration: configuration, delegate: nil, delegateQueue: OperationQueue.main)
```

Then I generate the request which stupidly enough needs an URL in the constructor:

```
var request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: "www.nil.com")!) // can't initialize without url
request.url = nil
```

Adding url with query parameters (you can just set the URL in your case, I have a tool to handle a few cases):

```
   fileprivate func injectQueryParameters(request: inout URLRequest) {
        if let query = queryParameters.urlEncodedString {
            let toReturn = endpoint.url + "?" + query
            if let url = URL(string: toReturn) {
                request.url = url
            } else {
                print("Cannot prepare url: \(toReturn)")
            }
        } else {
            let toReturn = endpoint.url
            if let url = URL(string: toReturn) {
                request.url = url
            } else {
                print("Cannot prepare url: \(toReturn)")
            }
        }
    }
```

Then the form parameters. We mostly use JSON but anything goes here:

```
    fileprivate func injectFormParameters( request: inout URLRequest) {
        if let data = rawFormData {
            request.httpBody = data
        } else if let data = formParameters.urlEncodedString?.data(using: .utf8) {
            request.httpBody = data
        }
    }
```

And the headers:

```
    fileprivate func injectHeaders(request: inout URLRequest) {
        headers._parameters.forEach { (key, value) in
            if let stringValue = value as? String {
                request.setValue(stringValue, forHTTPHeaderField: key)
            }
        }
    }
```

So in the end the whole call looks something like:

```
    class func performRequest(request: URLRequest, callback: (([String: Any]?, NSError?) -> Void)?) {
        let configuration = URLSessionConfiguration.default
        let session = URLSession(configuration: configuration, delegate: nil, delegateQueue: OperationQueue.main)

        let task = session.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
            // Response is sent here
            if let data = data {
                callback?((try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: .allowFragments)) as [String: Any]?, error)
            } else {
                callback?(nil, error)
            }
        }
        task.resume()
    }
```

I hope this puts you on the right track. In general you do have a few open source libraries you might be interested in. Alamofire is probably still used in most cases.

Comment: would I be able to monitor the progress of an upload doing this ? I need to be able to extract a progress bar during the time it takes to upload. 

but currently just sending the data is a issue XD

Comment: Well URLSessionTaskDelegate should be able to receive those. Try using that one as a delegate to self. But you might start with just a successful upload first, then extend the functionality to receive the progress. Also note if you are connecting to a non-secure server (http) you will need to include a filed in your plist to allow arbitrary loads.

Comment: so if I do not use a delegate to send I can still at a different place receive progress updates on the individual files. ? just by invoking the URLSessionTaskDelegate ?

yea I have done that :) the reason I'm opting for http over https is that this app will run inside a protected bubble anyway.

Comment: The http was just a note why you may not be reaching the server at all. The delegate is there so you can try and use it. It should work but the question is if in this case it does support these callbacks (the progress). Otherwise start with this one to see that the upload does succeed and check some docs to see what you need to actually get the progress callback.

Comment: Thanks I'll give it a go :) 

The reason I'm not going for third party open software is because I feel that I need to reduce dependencies of third part software to the bare minimum in this project.

Comment: Why not use URLComponents and URLQueryItem instead of your injectQueryParameters function?

Comment: @jrturton It is not in scope but generally yes, use the tools that have been provided for you to use. But just to explain we are using a custom class here that works similar to a dictionary as in queryParameters["field"]=value. It is used for multiple cases, not just the query parameters but it is simply reused here as with all the functionality there is really no more reason to use a higher level tools. For instance the same is used for some OAUTH2 raw credential requests which need a similar encoded procedure.

Comment: well I've now tried to implement a solution based on your suggestion. and at least I'm now getting a error that Says something at least understandable. 

I'm getting an error saying unsupported url. is this because I'm trying to use an ip in stead of a dns name ?

Comment: XD a minor error on my part :) it was because I didn't supply the http:// in front of the IP hmm I wonder if my other solution had the same problem. :) Thanks for your help I'm now going to fight with the format but at least now the server responds with an error saying unexpected EOF :) I'll mark your solution as the solution as this proved that the connection could be established.

Comment: Great. It seems legit to try your version now. That is why I usually insist that you first establish a most simple version of the request and once that one works you should try and upgrade it. In most cases you just find out there is a trivial mistake in the code.